# Cannot find symbol method execute(String)-Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods

The word "execute" in the code is causing the error which is saying cannot find symbol method execute(String). Can anyone help in resolving the error pls? Thanks

```
public void onClickGetWeather(View v) {

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCountry);
    String location = editText.getText().toString();

    weather_fragment task = new weather_fragment();
    try {
        double temp = task.execute(location).get();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("Temperature: " + temp);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

weather_fragment code:

```
public class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        double temp = 0.0f;

        try {
            temp = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is weather_fragment?

Comment: do you have a method called execute(String) in the class weather_fragment???

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic weather_fragment is a class where it works out an asynchronous task. It is a fragment

Comment: Can you show us your `weather_fragment` code ?

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa this is the code i have in the weather_fragment class

Comment: public class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

            String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

            double temp = 0.0f;

            try {
                temp = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return temp;

        }
    }

Comment: @JonasCz i edited it up here

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `execute(string)`on an object of type `weather_fragment` not on your AsyncTask of type `WeatherAsyncTask`.

You need to call your async task this way :

```
WeatherAsyncTask task = new WeatherAsyncTask();
task.execute(string);
```

So if you really want to start your asynctask through an instance of `weather_fragment` you will need something like this:

```
public class weather_fragment ... {

    public Double execute(String s){
        new WeatherAsyncTask().execute(string);
        // You must get the Double to return from the
        // onPostExecute(Double d) of the WeatherAsyncTask
        ...
    }

    public class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class **weather_fragment** needs a method that takes an `String` argument, 
if you already have a method called like this, then **[overload it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)** (i.e write another with the same name but with a string as parameter...) b ut if no then define it one